# Inserção no final de uma lista encadeada C

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Eu gostaria de saber como percorrer a lista para que eu possa adicionar um novo No no final dela, no caso na posição no->prox do ultimo no presente na lista.
Aqui tá o meu código:

```
typedef struct lista {
   struct no *prim;
} Lista;

typedef struct no {
   char *nome;
   char *apelido;
   char *email;
   struct no *prox;
} No;

void adicionar(Lista* lista, No var){
   No* novo = malloc(sizeof(No));

   novo->nome = var.nome;
   novo->apelido=var.apelido;
   novo->email=var.email;

   if (lista->prim == NULL){
      lista->prim = novo;
   }
   else{

   }
}
```

Minha dúvida é sobre o que colocar nesse else para que essa inserção seja feita.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa apenas de utilizar um `while` para ir passando nos nós enquanto não chegar ao ultimo. O ultimo é o que tem o `->prox` a `NULL`.

Assim:

```
...
else{
    No* atual = Lista->prim; //começar no primeiro
    while (atual->prox != NULL){ //navegar até ao fim
        atual = atual->prox;
    }

    atual->prox = novo; //colocar o novo nó no fim
}
```

Agora isto só irá funcionar se cada vez que cria um nó novo para por no fim, ou como primeiro nó, configurar o seu `->prox` corretamente, especificando `NULL`, que é algo que não está a fazer.

Por isso na criação do nó deve adicionar:

```
No* novo = malloc(sizeof(No));
novo->prox = NULL; //<--isto
```

Comment: Ahh, entendi agora, eu não tava inicializando o novo->prox como NULL, por isso tava dando erro de execução.
Obrigado.